# Can I enter data from winform to excel and take another cell calculation result?

Tags: vb.net, excel, winforms

I want to make a calculator in winform using complicated excel function so my current plan is to enter the data in winform in the textbox here

[image]

into the white cell here:

[image]

and take the calculation results from the orange cell on the second pic to show on the results part of the winform after calculate was pressed. Do you guys have any idea how to do this or a better way to make the calculator?

I was thinking it needed to use excel because it uses excel formula like intercept, slope, lon, and statistical function gamma. Thanks

Comment: [Intercept and slope](http://paulcockram.blogspot.co.id/2015/03/c-calculate-slope-intercept-and-rsquared.html) can be calculated directly, while gamma is available as [built-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.statisticformula.gammafunction.aspx). It's almost as if C# is a mature, general programming language already used for business purpose around the world.

Comment: I don't get the reason for using an excel sheet. Reading from and writing to it will take much longer than calculating it directly... also your calculator would "depend" on excel... I suggest to calculate everything directly in C#

Comment: @DirkReichel the problem is that the calculation i am using is really complicated. It has to count the amount of data entered, the condition of each data, the rank and lon of another lon, and addition if the previous cell has a value.
This is too complicated for a beginner like me so the easiest way i can think of is the one i am asking. Thanks.